# How to get localized message in custom tag in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, dependency-injection

In my application there is a custom tag(extending BodyTagSupport).There is a requirement to get the localized message from the properties file in the Tag.I define messageSource in dispatcher-servlet.xml file.Now how can I use this in the tag file.please help me.

```
    <bean name="messageSource"
    class="com.application.core.TestResourceBundleMessageResource">
    <property name="basename" value="welcome" />
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can define your message source in applicationContext instead of dispactcher servlet config, following is one solution:

Create the following class:

```
public class SpringContextUtil implements ApplicationContextAware {
    private static ApplicationContext applicationContext;     

    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext context) throws BeansException {
        applicationContext = context;
    }

    public static ApplicationContext getApplicationContext() {
        return applicationContext;
    }
}
```

In your applicationContext file add this:
<bean class="appropriate.package.SpringContextUtil" />

Now in your custom tag class you can do:

```
(TestResourceBundleMessageResource)SpringContextUtil.getApplicationContext().getBean("messageSource");
```

This works because we now have a reference to applicationContext and we can obtain by calling static get method of SpringContextUtil.